# Dynamic vertical text vertical align issue

Tags: html, css

I have some text which could be different on different pages. I need to make it align vertically middle. There is some problem because of less width for text.

```css
.vertical-text-block {
  width: 40px;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  float: left;
  background-color: grey;
}
.vertical-text {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-size: 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="vertical-text-block">
  <span class="vertical-text">ASHWANI SHARMA</span>
</div>
```

It should look like the image attached below:

[image]

Comment: include your markup

Answer (score 1):

I added `right: 50%`, `transform-origin: right` and removed `transform: translateY()`

```css
.vertical-text-block {
  width: 40px;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  float: left;
  background-color: grey;
  background-image: linear-gradient(darkgrey 0%, darkgrey 50%, lightgrey 50%);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.vertical-text {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  right: 50%;                      /* 1 */
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-size: 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  /*transform: translateY(-50%);*/ /* 2 */
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transform-origin: right;         /* 3 */
}
```

```html
<div class="vertical-text-block">
  <span class="vertical-text">ASHWANI SHARMA</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Nhan for your answer. It helped a bit but if text is little larger (e.g.: "American Leadership Index") then it move to top instead of middle.

Answer (score 1):

i made a small change to the DOM and was able to achieve it,i.e **centering the text , irrespective of its length** .

Made a small change to the DOM .

```
<div class="vertical-text-wrap">
<div class="vertical-text-block">
</div>
<span class="vertical-text">American Leadership Index</span>
</div>
```

Added an extra wrapper , *hope it is allowed*.

```css
.vertical-text-wrap {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px 20px;
}
.vertical-text-block {
  width: 40px;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  float: left;
  background-color: grey;
}
.vertical-text {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  left: -35%;
  font-size: 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform: translateY(50%) rotate(-90deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="vertical-text-wrap">
  <div class="vertical-text-block">

  </div>
  <span class="vertical-text">American Leadership Index</span>
</div>
```

Catch here is , when text becomes shorter , the `left` position of `span.vertical-text` has to be adjusted.

But hey , it is vertically centered :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can also do it this way http://codepen.io/Danstan/pen/QGWggO
Just add the translateX and translateY correctly on .vertical-text everything will be at the center

```
.vertical-text {
font-size:8px;
text-transform: uppercase;
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
white-space: nowrap;
-webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%) rotate(90deg);
transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%) rotate(90deg); white-space: nowrap;font-size: 10px;}
```

Comment: its not working as well with the different characters length